# How can you translate the mathematical statement 5=5 into a second order symbolic logic statement?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics

Hi I'm trying to describe the statement 5=5 using symbolic logic.  I initially attempted to describe this into English as:

> There is such a thing x and such a thing y, such that x is equivalent to y, iif for all x, x equals {a,b,c,d,e} AND for all y, y equals {a,b,c,d,e}.

and then more formally as:

> (x)(y)((x=y)≡(∀x(x={ a, b, c, d, e}) ∧ ∀y(y={ a, b, c, d, e}))

Is this correct? Does it even make sense?

Comment: It follows directly from the axioms of set theory.

Answer (score 7):

`(5=5)` [is already an atomic sentence in **FOL<sub>=</sub>**](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~snburris/htdocs/FALL00/SLIDES/chap5.pdf). It evaluates to true. If you wanted, you could get unnecessarily complicated and say something like `∀x∀y(((x=5)∧(y=5))→(x=y))` but this idea is already incorporated into what `=` does.

Equality in FOL (or SOL for that matter) is defined outside of the logic (in metalogical terms [as an *equivalence class*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class), yadda yadda) so we can just use it out of the box. Set theory does something a bit funkier with equality (of sets), but vanilla FOL/SOL doesn't know anything about sets.